# Regex // does not function properly

Tags: php, regex

I been trying to come up with the best way to do a php comment line with Regex. The double line starts like "//", an example of a php comment would be "// hello world". The problem with my comment is that it is not registering properly on some rare occasions. I figured that my Regex might be written wrong. Here is the code:

```
      \/\/.+?$

      \/\/*.+?$

      \/\/*.+?

      \/\/*[^>].+?

      \/\/*[^>]*.+?
```

I tried different variations and combinations. But I cannot find the perfect Regex.

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to capture the following:

```
code_line_1
//comment_1
code_line_2
code_line_3 //comment_2
```

Regex /`\/\/(.*)`/g seems to do the job for me by capturing the comments only.

Optionally you can use /`(\/\/.*)`/g to capture the slashes as well.

PHP comments:

```
<?php
    echo 'This is a test'; // This is a one-line c++ style comment
?>

<h1>This is an <?php # echo 'simple';?> example</h1>
```

Maybe catch with regex:
/`<\?php(.*?)\?>/`gs

Does it work for you?

Comment: I been trying `\?\>` for the php comment but that does not seem to work neither

Comment: Try to play with regex101. For example here is answer on the php comments: https://regex101.com/r/cH5tO7/2

Comment: I was talking about the end of the ?> line

Comment: What if the double slash is inside a string? `$a = "Hello \\ World"`? What if the string is multiline?

Comment: @ColOfAbRiX You have a point that solution is not universal. 

However, it seems that  $a = "Hello \\ World"; doesn't contain, any comment. Value of a is just "Hello \ World" - first backslash is being removed. Maybe you are referring to " $a = "Hello // World" - which would be indeed comment, but that piece of line is invalid syntactically.